# Unable to send_keys selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, exception, sendkeys

I have a problem inserting text in a box using **send_keys**, as it returns the error: "*ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable*".

Through inspection it seems that the input should go either within the first 2 <*span*> (first 2 HTML code lines) or replacing "Città o Stazione" (second 2 HTML code lines):

```html
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="opacity: 0.5;">
<span style="opacity: 1;"></span>

<span class="placeholder-start-typing">
   "Città o Stazione"
</span>
```

But both of them return the same error.
Here is the code I'm trying:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    
# for first case:
insertion1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//span[@style="opacity: 1;"]')
insertion1.click()
insertion1.send_keys('some city or station')
    
# for second case:
insertion2 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'placeholder-start-typing')
insertion2.click()
insertion2.send_keys('some city or station')
```

What am I doing wrong?
Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Input should be the one getting the send keys most likely.

Comment: It is! When the box was filled the text was in between the <span> so I didn't think about input but it actually made a lot more sense, thanks!